# picking random text from xml source in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, random

I am trying to select a random Bible verse from XML files I already have. I'd like to extract a random verse, display it then also display the verse number and book name.

I have several XML files so converting them to Plist might be a hassle and I am not sure if I use a dictionary that I can also extract the chapter number and book name.

The XML files look like this...

```
    <bible translation="KJV">
    <testament name="Old">

        <book index="1" name="Genesis">
            <chapter index="1">
                <verse index="1" text="In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."/>
                <verse index="2" text="And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."/>

                <!-- THE REST OF THE XML HERE -->

            </chapter>
       </book>
</testament>
```

Any idea on how I can select a random verse in and then display the text, book name and chapter number?

Comment: Could you post a small sample for how your plist file looks?  I've been trying to do this as well, but keep running into formatting problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple solution would be to take your XML file and format it as a *'Property List'* (plist) file - these can be handled easily in Objective-C. Essentially a *'Property List'* is just an XML file so the effort in converting it should be minimal.

You can then fill an array or dictionary with the contents of your 'plist' file and simply generate a random number to use as the index to select an object from your array. There's plenty of info around the web for how to handle plist files, a simple tutorial you can check out [here](http://hayageek.com/plist-tutorial/)

Comment: It will be hard for me to put these in a plist format since I have 8 versions and so 8 different xml files that each has a huge database inside. IS there anyway to quickly change these files into plist? If so what code should I use to import the plist into an array?
Thanks!!

Comment: Well if you create a plist then open it in an application like 'dashcode' you'll be able to see the XML source code of the plist file. What I would do is then just edit your XML file into a similar format as the plist. To split things up simply create an array.

Comment: I created this plist. But I needed to create it as dictionary so I have the book names as the keys. 
 then i used this:
 NSDictionary *plisttext2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"text2.plist"];
How would I be able to generate a random string from this dictionary 

<dict>
 <key>Genesis</key>
 <dict>
  <key>0</key>
  <string>In the beginning God</string>
  <key>1</key>
  <string>random0</string>
 </dict>
 <key>Numbers</key>
 <dict>
  <key>0</key>
  <string>And the earth was.</string>
  <key>1</key>
  <string>random2</string>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random book number between 1 and the highest book number you have, generate a random chapter number between 1 and the number of chapters in that book, finally generate a random number between 1 and the number of verses in that chapter. From there, you can use the three generated numbers to pick the correct verse.